# Pass real part of a complex array to a subroutines in fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90

Is it possible to pass real part of a complex array to a subroutine in Fortran without storing the real part in another array and pass that? e.g. instead of

```
Z = complex array;

X = real(Z)

call foo(X)
```

Do the following

```
Z = complex array

call foo(real(Z))
```

This gives me a compiler error! I am using an intel compiler ifort.

Comment: As per Bálint Aradi's answer, yes, this is allowed. The compiler error is likely coming from somewhere else. Please update your question with the compiler error, version, and minimal (actual code) example.

Comment: It may also depend on your procedure foo, maybe you use some features that require an explicit interface and don't provide one or there may be some other kind of programming error. Without more code and the error message this question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, it works:

```
module testmod
  implicit none

  integer, parameter :: dp = kind(1.0d0)

contains

  subroutine realsub(array)
    real(dp), intent(in) :: array(:)
    print *, array
  end subroutine realsub

end module testmod


program testprog
  use testmod
  implicit none

  complex(dp) :: array(3)

  array(:) = [ (1.0_dp, 1.0_dp), (3.0_dp, 2.0_dp), (-1.0_dp, 3.0_dp) ]
  call realsub(real(array))

end program testprog
```